# Add Border to the bottom of SELECTED segmented control

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add a border to the selected segmented control.  Currently, I have code which sets the border of 3px to the bottom of the whole segmented control:

```
CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
bottomBorder.borderWidth = 3;
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height - bottomBorder.borderWidth, self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width, bottomBorder.borderWidth);
[self.segmentedControl.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

However, I want to add this border ONLY to the selected segmented control.  How do I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//Connect action to segmented control.

- (IBAction)segmentedControlAction:(id)sender {

if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"First Segment (Feed) Selected");

    //Remove SuperLayer when segment is selected
    [_bottomBorder removeFromSuperlayer];

    // Creating new layer for selection
    _bottomBorder  = [CALayer layer];
    _bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    _bottomBorder.borderWidth = 3;

    // Calculating frame
    CGFloat width = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width/3;
    CGFloat x = self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex * width;
    CGFloat y = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height - _bottomBorder.borderWidth;
    _bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(x, y,width, _bottomBorder.borderWidth);

    // Adding selection to segment
    [self.segmentedControl.layer addSublayer:_bottomBorder];

}
else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Second Segment (Stations) Selected");

        //Remove SuperLayer when segment is selected
        [_bottomBorder removeFromSuperlayer];

        // Creating new layer for selection
        _bottomBorder  = [CALayer layer];
        _bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        _bottomBorder.borderWidth = 3;

        // Calculating frame
        CGFloat width = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width/3;
        CGFloat x = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width/3;
        CGFloat y = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height - _bottomBorder.borderWidth;
        _bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(x, y,width, _bottomBorder.borderWidth);

        // Adding selection to segment
        [self.segmentedControl.layer addSublayer:_bottomBorder];


    }

else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
       NSLog(@"Third Segment (Events) Selected");

        //Remove SuperLayer when segment is selected
        [_bottomBorder removeFromSuperlayer];

        // Creating new layer for selection
        _bottomBorder  = [CALayer layer];
        _bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        _bottomBorder.borderWidth = 3;

        // Calculating frame
        CGFloat width = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width/3;
        CGFloat x = self.view.bounds.size.width - self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width/3;
        CGFloat y = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height - _bottomBorder.borderWidth;
        _bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(x, y,width, _bottomBorder.borderWidth);

        // Adding selection to segment
        [self.segmentedControl.layer addSublayer:_bottomBorder];

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing same operation in all three if else case ? Why can't you write that once in the method body ? Like I wrote it in my answer. This answer seems a mix of the previous two answers and looks messy. If you are calculating the frame dynamically, you don't need to use the if else block

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to dynamically add the selection:

```
// Removing previous selection
[bottomBorder removeFromSuperlayer];

// Creating new layer for selection
bottomBorder             = [CALayer layer];
bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
bottomBorder.borderWidth = 3;

// Calculating frame
CGFloat width            = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width/3;
CGFloat x                = self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex * width;
CGFloat y                = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height - bottomBorder.borderWidth;
bottomBorder.frame       = CGRectMake(x, y,width, bottomBorder.borderWidth);

// Adding selection to segment
[self.segmentedControl.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

You need to remove the previous selection when new choice is selected, for that purpose make the `bottomBorder` layer as a member variable.

Comment: This works, except I cant figure out how to make bottomBorder layer a member variable to account for when a new choice is selected.  Can you please give me an example?  Thanks!

Comment: @JoshO'Connor: Just do like : `@implementation YourClass{ CALayer *bottomBorder;}`

Comment: This was VERY close to being 100% correct. All we needed to do was hook this up to an action which is connected to the segmented control.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I converted the Objective-C solutions into swift3 it is working for me, My Segment controller width is equal to View width

```
@IBAction func SegmentAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        self.segmentBottomBorder?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        self.segmentBottomBorder = CALayer()
        self.segmentBottomBorder?.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.segmentBottomBorder?.borderWidth = 3
        let width: CGFloat = sender.frame.size.width/CGFloat(sender.numberOfSegments)
        let x = CGFloat(sender.selectedSegmentIndex) * width
        let y = sender.frame.size.height - (self.segmentBottomBorder?.borderWidth)!

        self.segmentBottomBorder?.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: (self.segmentBottomBorder?.borderWidth)!)
        sender.layer.addSublayer(self.segmentBottomBorder!)
}
```

Comment: what's "width"?

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it. it is working

Comment: not working. I see the red border for a second and then it disappears. Testing on iOS 12.

Comment: in iOS 12, first you have to make segment style as plain with out borders. in iOS 13 in storyboard we can change segment style as Plain.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the proper way, but you can give it a shot.

At the time you load the segment control, try this in viewdidload, so the layer gets added according to the selectedsegment button

```
if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {

    CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
    bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    bottomBorder.borderWidth = 3;
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height - bottomBorder.borderWidth, self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width/2, bottomBorder.borderWidth);

    [self.segmentedControl.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];


}else if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==1){

    //change the border layer frame


} else if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==2){
    //change the border layer frame
  }
```

Again in the segmentcontrol action method, you can alter these changes